# The problem of not being able to send the method to the interface

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, interface, overriding

friends I can't send my methods in UserService to IUserService with @Override.I'm getting the error in the picture, if you can help I would be very grateful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wysUB.png)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified that your `UserService` implements the `IUserService` interface.

You need to change your class signature to the following:

```
public class UserService implements IUserService
```